# javaw.exe pdb not found

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio-2010, java-native-interface

I am building a java application which call some function of a c++ dll using jni. When I tried to build my dll I get a pop up saying that debugging information for 'javaw.exe' cannot be found or does not match.Cannot find or open the pdb file. I have already set my environment variable. Is it normal and if not is there a way to avoid it ?

```
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\bin\javaw.exe', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9200.16384_none_418c2a697189c07f\comctl32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\3D Vision\nvStInit64.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6871_none_08e717a5a83adddf\msvcr90.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wsock32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\bin\verify.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\bin\java.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\bin\zip.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\anael\Documents\INF2990\Cadriciel\Exe\DLL\INF2990.dll', Symbols loaded.
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'javaw.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\bin\jawt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

Comment: And the question is.... ? Unless you built a javaw.exe *with pdb-debugging info*, or downloaded said-same pdb database along with the javaw.exe toolchain you're running, you won't be finding it anytime soon.

Comment: my two questions are is it normal and is there a way t o avoid it ?

Comment: Yes it is normal. I simply means the javaw.exe you're using does not have accompanying symbols for debugging assistance. In most cases your JNI work will not need them. Were the same message being given to you concerning *your* code (your JNI) you'd have issues, but as you've described it is normal for a release-build with no accompanying debugging symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is normal.

Visual Studio is just saying you that it can't find pdb files required for showing C++ source code while debugging - but not your source code, but the source code of javaw.exe itself (which you don't need, as, if there is problem, the probability of finding bug is in your code, and not in Oracle's is pretty big).